# Combine columns of dataframe into new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and working with [DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html). I'm looking at the documentation for [Merge,Join,Concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), and it's probably staring me right in the face, but I'm still having trouble transposing the data the way I need it.

I have data that looks like this ( R rows x 4302 columns ):

```
| w:350 |       r:350 | w:351 |   r:351 |  ...  | w:2499 |      r:2499 | w:2500 |  r:2500 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   350 | -3.0998e-04 |   351 |  0.0001 |  ...  |   2499 | -3.6000e-05 |   2500 |  0.0004 |
|   350 | -1.8316e-03 |   351 | -0.0008 |  ...  |   2499 | -3.1124e-04 |   2500 | -0.0004 |
|   350 | -1.0520e-03 |   351 | -0.0014 |  ...  |   2499 |  4.0166e-04 |   2500 |  0.0012 |
|   350 | -3.4060e-04 |   351 |  0.0006 |  ...  |   2499 |  1.2782e-03 |   2500 |  0.0012 |
```

That I want to look like this ( X rows x 2 columns ):

```
|     x |           y |
-----------------------
|   350 | -3.0998e-04 |
|   350 | -1.8316e-03 |
|   350 | -1.0520e-03 |
|   350 | -3.4060e-04 |
|   351 |      0.0001 |
|   351 |     -0.0008 |
|   351 |     -0.0014 |
|   351 |      0.0006 |
...
|  2499 | -3.6000e-05 |
|  2499 | -3.1124e-04 |
|  2499 |  4.0166e-04 |
|  2499 |  1.2782e-03 |
|  2500 |      0.0004 |
|  2500 |     -0.0004 |
|  2500 |      0.0012 |
|  2500 |      0.0012 |
```

I guess you can think of it as a DataFrame of rows of multiple sets of x,y data, that I want combined into a DataFrame of rows of a single set of x,y data. Or in other words, each row is currently a graph of x,y data. And I need a single collection of x,y data of all the graphs.

I've tried this, but it's not working (probably because the column names not named the same). It's also probably not the most efficient way to do what I'm trying to do. Here `output` is my original data, and `outputxy` is the transposed data that I want.

```
outputxy = pandas.DataFrame()
for i in range(0, len(output.columns), 2):
    outputxy = pandas.concat([output.iloc[:, i:i+2], outputxy])
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can using [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html), if you need column name to be x, y , you can [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) it

PS: this method , does not require the order of your columns.

```
pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),stubnames=['w','r'],i='index',j='drop',sep=':').reset_index(drop=True)
Out[205]: 
     w         r
0  350 -0.000310
1  350 -0.001832
2  350 -0.001052
3  350 -0.000341
4  351  0.000100
5  351 -0.000800
6  351 -0.001400
7  351  0.000600
```

Comment: Sorry for late accept! This worked brilliantly. Thank you very much. I was not even aware of that function. It is so powerful :)

Comment: @delrocco yw~ :-)

Answer (score 1):

Can use melt and drop as shown below

```
df =  '''
w1  r1 w2 r2
1  14 4  23
2  15 5 32
3  16 6 33
'''

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['X'] = pd.melt(df.iloc[:,::2]).drop('variable',1)
df1['Y'] = pd.melt(df.iloc[:,1::2]).drop('variable',1)

print df1

  X   Y
0  1  14
1  2  15
2  3  16
3  4  23
4  5  32
5  6  33
```

Answer (score 0):

You could name the columns equivocally with:

```
['X': [ output.iloc[:, i:i+1]],'Y': [ [ output.iloc[:, i+1:i+2]]
```

You could also place an index with the number of rows.